# With Graphicsmagick, how to combine 2 images and text in a certain format?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I need to combine 2 images and a short text into one image, in the format that the first image is at the top spanning a row, and the other image at bottom left, the text at bottom right.

The produced image is 400px * 600px, the input images can be any size, if the first image is less than  400px, it will be centered at the top

Is it possible with Graphicsmagick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you already have two images called:

1. **top.png** (image at the top spanning a row)
2. **left.png** (other image at bottom left)

first of all you have to create the third missing image (called **text.png**) containing your text:

```
gm convert -size 200x300 xc:#7F0000 -pointsize 80 -font Arial -fill white -draw "text 10,150 'text'" text.png
```

then you can compose the two images in the bottom part (creating an image called **bottom.png**):

```
gm montage left.png -geometry 200x300+0+0 text.png -tile 2x1 bottom.png
```

and finally you can compose upper and lower parts with:

```
gm montage top.png -geometry 400x300+0+0 bottom.png -tile 1x2 result.png
```

the result will be an image called **result.png**, size: 400x600

top.png:

[image]

left.png:

[image]

result.png:

[image]

*Tested on Windows with GraphicsMagick 1.3.18 2013-03-10 Q8*

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer and sorry for the late acceptance